# Complex many to many query with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got two tables, one is a users table, the other is a tweets table. Users can follow other users and users can favorite tweets (both many to many relationships).

Here are the classes, which create the correct tables in my db:

```
follow = db.Table('follow',
    db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('following_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    following = db.relationship('User', 
        secondary = follow, 
        primaryjoin = (follow.c.follower_id == id), 
        secondaryjoin = (follow.c.following_id == id), 
        backref = db.backref('followers'))

favorite = db.Table('favorite',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('tweet_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tweet.id'))
)

class Tweet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    favorited = db.relationship('User', secondary=favorite,
        backref=db.backref('favorites'))
```

Now, the query I'm trying to perform is to select all the favorited tweets from the users a given user is following. So something to the effect of:

```
user = User.query.get(user_id)
Tweet.query.filter(Tweet.favorited.in_(user.following))
```

This doesn't work because the `in_` method doesn't support model objects. I'm stumped on how to do it without iterating through the arrays, which I don't think would be at all efficient. Any thoughts? Bonus points for doing it in one query...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
user_id = ?
qry = (db.session.query(Tweet)
        .join(User, Tweet.favorited)
        .filter(User.followers.any(User.id == user_id))
        )
```